# what about static class in asp.net web application and how it works either as session or application variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

If i stored the user information in static class , it will be
overwrite by another user once they logged in . how static class act
in web application in asp.Net ?

Comment: Not to be unpleasant, but if you don't know how static object works just stop your code and take few minutes to understand these basics.

Comment: i know what is static class basically . in one project, alcatel Lucent client , all the user information are stored in static class once they login  . but still it is giving unique information for users .  as some said here , it should be overwrite by new user info . is it possible to keep the user wise information on static class ?

Comment: There is no way to keep user info in static simple fields instead use [ThredStatic] like Mathias said but like he discouraged to use ^^. You have a very bad solution using a static collection which stored user info with unique key which let you find the right user. But it is not recommand to adopt this kind of solution.

Answer (score 1):

A static class behaves in ASP.NET in the same way as in any other environment: .NET applications run inside a sandbox called `AppDomain`and static values are available withint the `AppDomain`.

In other words: a static value isn't thread-scoped, and this means that it's an application domain-wide concern. That is, any user from any thread can modify a static value.

There's an exception to the rule: the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute, which can be applied to static class fields and its values will be only available in the thread that they were created, and if the thread ends, the so-called values are lost. **Anyway, don't use `[ThreadStatic]` in ASP.NET, because the Web server (like IIS/OWIN) may process a requests using more than a thread.**

Comment: @Micky I can change it...

Comment: @Micky No problem ;p

Answer (score 0):

The values you add to a static field in a class are defined for all instances of that class.

If you store user information in a static field, it will be shared by all the instances of your class in the running web process. Every requests will read/write the value of this static field. You should not do that because it will lead to incorrect data.

In a web application, you will have a lot of multiple requests that happens at the same time so it is for this reason you need to use the asp .net session object.

The information you store in the session object is guaranted to be unique for each user sessions by the runtime.

Comment: so application variable also act in same manner of static class in asp.net . am i right ?